# Are forces an abstract quantity whose nature can only be discussed with the consequences it has on reality?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

In this lecture-pdf by Carnegie Mellon [(here)](https://www.cs.rpi.edu/%7Etrink/Courses/RobotManipulation/lectures/lecture12.pdf)<sup>1</sup>, the following quote is said:

> You cannot measure force, only its effects: deformation of structures, acceleration.

I thought about this statement a bit and thought it to be accurate as 'force' is some abstract quantity which we say should be mathematically equal to $ m \cdot a$ but then consider the following system:

Two bodies in vacuum with mass $m_1$ and $m_2$ separated by a distance $d$, isolated such that no external influence is there , then then the force which $m_1$ acts on $m_2$ is given by:

$$ F_{ 1 \to 2} = \frac{Gm_1 m_2}{d^2} \vec{r_{2 \to 1} }$$

Where,  $\vec{r_{2 \to 1} }$ is the unit vector pointing from the second body to the first.

Now, without directly seeing the effect of the force, we were still able to measure the force with no problems. So, what exactly have I missed in interpreting the quoted statement?

---

<sup>1</sup> M. Mason, Lecture Notes, Topic: "12. Foundations of Statics", *Mechanics of Manipulation*, Carnegie Mellon University. Available: [12th lecture in this site](https://www.cs.rpi.edu/%7Etrink/Courses/RobotManipulation/lectures/).

Comment: "Now, without directly seeing the effect of the force, we were still able to measure the force with no problems."  How could you do this?

Comment: Using the newton's gravitational law. You put in the parameters and it gives you the force..doesn't it?

Comment: When I stand on my bathroom scale it measures the force of gravity on my body. Maybe the quote from the lecture needs context.

Comment: That’s not a *measurement* of force. For example, how would you verify that Newton’s gravitation law is correct?

Comment: Here is how I think about it: Newton's law of gravity can always be used and it's known to be consistent with observed accelerations. So, we can say newton's law of gravity is the true expression for the abstract idea. However, the author states that only the effects of force can be measured but here without even looking at the 'effects' i.e: evolution of motion, I was able to know the force.

Comment: Well that's the only thing he says on page-4 about it. I read till around page-12 but haven't seen further discussion on it. @BobD

Comment: How do you think the value of $G$ in your gravitation equation was measured? And how do you think you measure the mass of the two bodies?

Comment: @BobD Your bathroom scale doesn't "measure a force" at all. It just contains a flexible device (for example a spring) and tells you how much the spring is stretched, but on a scale labeled "pounds" or "kg" not "inches" or "mm".

Comment: On second thought, since mass is defined using force ( I think?) does that mean mass is measured by it's effects?@alephzero

Comment: Force is the divergence of some potential field.  So if you know the potential energy you can calculate the associated force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between *measuring* the gravitational force between two bodies and *calculating* what it should be from some equation or another.

For example, let's say you want to verify that Newton's law of gravitation is actually correct.  How would you do it?  Given two known masses $M$ and $m$, you would have to measure the force $F$ and the distance $d$, and then verify that they were related via $F = G \frac{Mm}{d^2}$.

---

I see a similar mistake in my intro lab class every single year.  The students are asked to experimentally verify the impulse-momentum theorem by using a cart and a combination of a force meter and a position sensor.  They roll the cart towards the force sensor and keep track of its velocity.  Then the cart bounces off the force sensor and its velocity reverses direction.  Using the motion sensor, they can calculate the velocity and therefore the change in momentum; using the force sensor, they can integrate the force over time and obtain the impulse.  Upon comparison, the numbers should be the same to within experimental uncertainty.

However, every year there is at least one group which measures the change in velocity with the position sensor, and then **calculates the impulse** as $I = \Delta p$ because that's what's in their textbook.  They then proudly demonstrate that $I=\Delta p$ with 0% error.

---

The point of this is that a **measurement** of force necessarily involves observing the effect of that force on some measuring device.  It could be the extension or compression of a spring, or perhaps some acceleration which is induced in a moving object, but the point remains that you cannot measure force without it having an effect on *something*.

---

> As a follow-up, is mass only known due to its effects?

Yes.  How you'd measure it depends on [which notion of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Inertial_vs._gravitational_mass) you're trying to measure.  The *inertial mass* $m$ is the quantity which appears in $F=ma$, so a measurement of it would require measuring some net force and the subsequent acceleration of the body, and then calculating $F/a$.

On the other hand, the (passive) *gravitational mass* $M$ is the constant which appears in $F_g = Mg$, and a measurement of it would require measuring the gravitational force and the free-fall acceleration $g$, and then calculationg $F_{g}/g$.

The fact that these two quantities are equal to one another is a mysterious coincidence in Newtonian physics (but is explained by the general theory of relativity).

Comment: As a follow-up, is mass only known due to its effects?

Comment: @Buraian I have updated my answer to address your follow-up.

Comment: Now, I'm even more confused.. you need a mass to define a force and you need a force to define a mass. it's all cyclic...

Comment: @Buraian Newton's second law says that the net force on a body is proportional to its acceleration.  You can measure a force by seeing how it deforms a spring; you can measure an acceleration by keeping track of position over time.  If you subject the same mass to different forces, you find that the force is indeed proportional to the acceleration.  There is nothing circular here.

Comment: @Buraian The name we give to the proportionality constant between force and acceleration is (inertial) mass.  It can be measured by measuring the force on an object (e.g. with a spring) and the acceleration of the object (e.g. by keeping track of position) and then dividing them.  Again, nothing circular here.

Comment: How do I measure the force being seeing how it deforms a spring? I think I would need some experimental procedure that doesn't involve mass to figure out the spring constant so that the argument is not circular.

Comment: @Buraian You take your favorite spring, hold one end fixed, and apply a force to the other end.  Define 1 Buraian as the amount of force required to stretch your spring by 1 cm.  Now you can use that spring to measure force in Buraians.

Comment: But stretching is not really a 'discrete' phenomenon, if I apply one buraian then the spring doesn't immediately stretch. The force must be applied over a time period and since the spring has an every changing compression force but when we do that the momentum of spring is also changing, so that problem is a lot more complicated than initially thought

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113853/discussion-between-j-murray-and-buraian).

Comment: "The point of this is that a measurement of force necessarily involves observing the effect of that force on some measuring device. " If I substitute the word *force* with any other physical quantity I end up with the same true statement. I do not think the peculiar case of the force can be explained this way. I'll try to explain why in an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is a representation of what happens in reality. Its like a chicken and the egg situation. Did the equation predict the force, or did the force predict the equation. Its actually kind of both (using strictly newtonian physics). Whether or not we knew the equation, the force would have the same effect, but since we are able to observe the effect the force has, we can then come up with the equation to predict what effect similar forces will have in the future.

As for the statement, its basically saying forces can only be measured by its effect on something else. We can figure out the gravitational FIELD of the earth, which won't change no matter what, but the force it exerts on us versus the sun is different, as per the equation you mentioned. Basically, forces aren't "things", they're the changing of things, like its shape (deformation) or its speed (acceleration)